# Jquery/JS: Получить содержимое сестры родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я думал это будет легко, но реально перепробовал уже все.
В общем, по клику на кнопку с классом `.button_flower`, мне нужно получить `html/text` дива `.catalogue_item_title`, то есть текст "Сливки".

```js
let name_buket = "";
$(".button_flower").click(function() {
  name_buket = $(this).parent().prev('.catalogue_item_title').html() // Почему то prev делает обращение к еще одному родителю, а не сестринскому элементу.

  name_buket = $(this).parent().parent().children('.catalogue_item_title') //Получаю объект из одного элемента, но не работает метод html()
  name_buket = $(this).closest('.catalogue_item_title') // Аналогично, получаю объект, но не могу вытянуть html

  $('#name_liked_buket').text(name_buket)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalogue_item">
  <div class="catalogue_item_title"><a href="/slivki.html">Сливки</a></div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_image"><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_desc">Букет невесты в нежных тонах из роз, с добавлением гипсофилы и рускуса. Бутоньерка для жениха в подарок.</div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_price">1050</div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_more"><a href="#" id="go" class="button_flower">Заказать</a></div>
</div>


<div id="name_liked_buket">+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> по клику на кнопку с классом .button_flower, мне нужно получить html/text дива ".catalogue_item_title", то есть текст "Сливки".

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
let name_buket = "";
$(".button_flower").click(function() {
  name_buket = $(this).parents('.catalogue_item').find('.catalogue_item_title').text()
  console.log(name_buket)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalogue_item">
  <div class="catalogue_item_title"><a href="/slivki.html">Сливки</a></div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_image"><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_desc">Букет невесты в нежных тонах из роз, с добавлением гипсофилы и рускуса. Бутоньерка для жениха в подарок.</div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_price">1050</div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_more"><a href="#" id="go" class="button_flower">Заказать</a></div>
</div>


<div id="name_liked_buket">+</div>
```

Вот вариант через родителей... Вот только нужно правильно понимать с чем ты имеешь дело.

```js
$(".button_flower").click(function() {
  let name_buket = $(this).parent().parent().children('.catalogue_item_title') 
  name_buket = name_buket.text()
  console.log(name_buket)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalogue_item">
  <div class="catalogue_item_title"><a href="/slivki.html">Сливки</a></div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_image"><img src="img/img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_desc">Букет невесты в нежных тонах из роз, с добавлением гипсофилы и рускуса. Бутоньерка для жениха в подарок.</div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_price">1050</div>
  <div class="catalogue_item_more"><a href="#" id="go" class="button_flower">Заказать</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.
Непоятно только, почему нельзя напрямую работать с parent>child, closest

Comment: @Amigo9876, все можно... Тут главное правильно понимать кто будет `parent`. ;) Ты ведь клацаешь по ссылке и `parent` у нее `<div class="catalogue_item_more">`...

Comment: @Amigo9876, смотри - я добавил вариант работы через `parent()`. И сличи с тем что делал ты.